TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment
Основной код =
        elif choice == "5":
        print(f"{COLOR_CODE['GREEN']}                                         Выполните все ниже перечисленные требования!")
        print(f"{COLOR_CODE['GREEN']}                                      Почты которые можно добавить: Gmail, hotmail, mail")
        print(f"{COLOR_CODE['GREEN']}                                     ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐")
        emailst = input(f"                                     │ > 1. Введите почту:")
        passwordst = input(f"                                     │ > 2. Введите пароль:")
        print(f"{COLOR_CODE['GREEN']}                                     └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘")
        try:
            with open("senders.json", "r") as f:
                senders = json.load
        except FileNotFoundError:
            senders = {}
        senders[emailst] = passwordst
        with open("senders.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(senders, f, indent=4)
            print(f"{COLOR_CODE['GREEN']}                                     > Почта {emailst} успешно добавлена в софт!{COLOR_CODE['GREEN']}")
            time.sleep(5)

Ошибка -
  File "C:\Users\Wizi\Desktop\ExSnoser 0.3 MOBILE\main.py", line 570, in main
senders[emailst] = passwordst
~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment

Вроде написанно все верно, программа получает всю информацию!
Другие функции использующие информацию(почт, пароли от почт) работают прекрасно!

Ты забыл скобки в строке senders = json.load.
senders = json.loads(f)


Там не только скобок не хватает, но и параметра

File "C:\Users\Wizi\Desktop\ExSnoser 0.3 MOBILE\main.py", line 567, in main
senders = json.load()
^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'

@Wizi, как функция json.load() должна догадаться, откуда ей данные читать? Нужно открытый файл параметром передать.

Значит, senders = json.load(f)

File "C:\Users\Wizi\Desktop\ExSnoser 0.3 MOBILE\main.py", line 564, in main
senders = json.load(f)
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Wizi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json_init_.py", line 293, in load
return loads(fp.read(),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Wizi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json_init_.py", line 346, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "C:\Users\Wizi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Wizi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 109 column 1 (char 5115)

Написал senders = json.load(f)

@Wizi "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 109 column 1 (char 5115)" значит там не json, либо кривой json.

Понял, сейчас проверю

Ураа пофиксил, спасибо

@u111 пожалуйста отредактируйте ответ. Добавте правильный вариант.
